# How To Close Popup Window Automatically When Its Not In Use?

Tags: javascript

I want a popup window to close automatically as soon as the user minimizes the window. My code is as follows:

```
<a href="#" onclick="Popup=window.open('fb.html','Popup','toolbar=no,location=no,status=yes,menubar=no,scrollbars=no,resizable=no,width=620,height=400,left=230,top=23'); return false;">
```

any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

See a [post](http://www.javascript-coder.com/window-popup/javascript-window-close.phtml) about programmatically opening and closing pop-ups.

For browser windows or tabs, I believe that you need the user to click a confirmation box (the confirmation is created by the browser as a security feature).

**Added** Think about your UX (User Experience) -- it is not usual for a user to think about minimizing a window. Perhaps you should provide a "close" button.

Also, investigate the various libraries such as [Boostrap modal popups](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#modals). They already have worked on the UX issues.

Answer (score 0):

There's no event that triggers when the window is minimized. The best you can do is to check the height and width at a set interval. Closing the browser window is trivial `Popup.close()` should do it.